when model summary() show 'ValueError: Undefined shapes are not supported.'
I facing a problem when defining layers, the model summary for sequential model got error
Images
This problem only show when I run the code on jupyter notebook, when using google colab to run this code, totally no problem for this row, just that google colab epoch training is very slow
python version 3.12
tensorflow version 2.17.0
keras version 3.4.1
I have try on Chatgpt and other sample, but everytime turn to error when sequential model stage.

Please include a minimal, reproducible example. I don't think I'm the only one who won't copy your code from the image letter by letter.

Plus, most likely seeing different things in Colab vs Jupyter Notebook is because the two have different environments. You list a few versions of things in your post but don't say if that is where it works or where it doesn't? Presumably you'd compare these things and share both. Did you look into what was suggested for here that shows the same error?

instead of sharing image, use texts, and describe your problem clearly.

I was also facing this issue, then I imported Lamba and it worked.
My model code:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda
efficient_model = Sequential()
efficient_model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
pretrained_model = EfficientNetB0(include_top=False,
                                  input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                                  pooling='avg',
                                  weights='imagenet')
for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
         layer.trainable = False
efficient_model.add(pretrained_model)
efficient_model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))


u should probably add as first layer "Input" layer with argument "shape" and type your feature shape, good luck!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I had the same problem. This Github thread suggests that this is a problem with the Tensorflow version and that downgrading to 2.15.x solves the problem. It worked for me, so you might want to try it.

add Input() layer on the first in sequential model, don't add input_shape with in any other layer, tensorflow has removed that feature.
same issue got with below model
"""
model = Sequential([
base_model,
Dropout(0.5),
# MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
# GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
Flatten(),
Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
Dense(len(categories), activation='softmax')

ans solved it by adding Input() layer, below is the solved code.
"""
model = Sequential([
Input(shape=(224,224,3)),
base_model,
Dropout(0.5),
# MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
# GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
Flatten(),
Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
Dense(len(categories), activation='softmax')

